# how to exec commands with php_seclib

Tags: php, shell, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

i want to upload a file to an sftp with key-authentification. Therefore i use phpseclib installed with composer. I can upload to an sftp with authentification with user and password, but with a keyfile i dont get any result or error or something: ( the php code is executeted in unix shell, not in an explorer )

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
    use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
    use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
    ...
    $loSftp                     = sftpConnection();
    function sftpConnection()
    {
        $ssh  = new SSH2('xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX');
        $key  = new RSA();
        $key->loadKey(file_get_contents('../keys/id_rsa'));
        if (!$ssh->login('MYUSERNAME', $key)) {
            exit('Login Failed');
        }
        echo PHP_EOL . "login done";
        echo PHP_EOL. 'connected: '. $ssh->isConnected();
        echo PHP_EOL. 'authenticated: '. $ssh->isAuthenticated();
        echo PHP_EOL. 'quitemode: '. $ssh->isQuietModeEnabled();
        echo PHP_EOL. 'test'. $ssh->exec('anycommandhere;', function($str) {
            echo '->'. $str;
        });
        return $ssh;
    }
```

Output:

```
Result:1
login done
connected: 1
authenticated: 1
quitemode:
test
```

i have to use ->exec(? because i need the keyfile)  but whatever command i use 'ls -ahl' or 'pwd' gives no output, even 'test' should output an error (finaly i want to use a 'cd folder; put myfile.txt').
also i cant use multiple exec as printed in the manual, this results in an error:

> Unable to open channel in ....
>   /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3842

what i am doing wrong ?

edit:
( or... is there an other phplib i can use ? )
edit2: output of the log:

https://pastebin.com/vBxUvCZT

Comment: Get the SSH logs by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and `echo $ssh->getLog();` after your `$ssh->exec()` call. Copy / paste the output and then post it to pastebin.com. Then edit your post to include the link and reply to your post, doing `@neubert` so that way I get a notification that this has been done. Then I'll take a look and see what I see!

Comment: @neubert thx for your help, i copied the output, link is in the post

Comment: Your SSH server identifies itself as `SSH-2.0-AZ_ADAPTER_SFTP_12_01`. I've never heard of that SSH server before. Based on the name I do wonder if it only supports SFTP and not actual SSH commands. Your post says "_i have to use ->exec(? because i need the keyfile)_". Needing a keyfile in no way means that you can't use SFTP commands. It's possible that the server (despite it's name) doesn't work with SSH2 commands but if so then that would have less to do with the use of a keyfile and more to do with the SSH server

Comment: I also wonder if interactive mode would work better (assuming `$ssh->nlist()` with the `SFTP` class doesn't). eg. `$ssh->write("anycommandhere\n"); echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');`. It's not unheard of for SSH servers to work with interactive mode only and not support individual one off commands. Interactive mode is what you'd use if you used PuTTY or ssh via the CLI to open up a shell on the remote server.

Comment: @neubert when i use $ssh  = new SSH2 i dont have a $ssh->put or a $ssh->get methode, i have to use $ssh->exec('put myfile somewhere'), isnt it ? if i use  $sftp = new SFTP then i can use ->put and ->get thats worrying me a little bit. what i have tried in the meanwhile: connecting per shell and uploading works, so i´ve done a workaround without phpseclib using now proc_open('sftp -i xxx $descriptorspec, $pipes); writing to a logfile and parsing that file. not satisfying but uploading

Comment: "_if i use $sftp = new SFTP then i can use ->put and ->get thats worrying me a little bit_". Why does that worry you? I cannot fathom a reason why it should...

Comment: @neubert i am worried, cause i cant use it when i make a new ssh2, should mean, if i use new sftp i cant use key authentification but can use put and get methods of the lib, if i use new ssh2 i can use key authetification but not the put and get method, just the exec

Comment: "_if i use new ssh2 i can use key authetification_". Yes. The SFTP class extends the SSH2 class. All methods in the SSH2 class exist in the SFTP class. The difference between the two is that the SFTP class constructor will error out if it can't make an SFTP connection _on top of_ the SSH2 connection whereas the SSH2 constructor does not error out.